# How can I remove all tics except extra tics?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, ticks

I made a Plot witz pgfplot and made a few extra ticks. Now I want only those extra ticks to be shown. I removed the numbers with `xticklabels={},` but the ticks are still there.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5 ,xmax=105,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel=,
    extra x ticks={0,30,50,70,100},
    extra x tick labels={{0},{30},{50},{70},{100}},
    extra x tick style={color=black},
    every x tick/.style={black},
    xticklabels={},
    ]
\addplot [red] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anybody help?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: To remove the ticks and not the labels, you have to set `xtick` instead of `xticklabels`, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automatic x ticks are suppressed by the special value `\empty`:

```
xtick=\empty

\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5 ,xmax=105,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel=,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,30,50,70,100},
    extra x tick labels={{0},{30},{50},{70},{100}},
    extra x tick style={color=black},
    every x tick/.style={black},
    ]
\addplot [red] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

But: "empty x ticks" + "extra ticks" = "x tick" without need for "extra ticks"?
Also the domain of the dummy function is changed to enhance its visilibity:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5 ,xmax=105,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel=,
    xtick={0, 30, 50, 70, 100},
    ]
\addplot[domain=0:10] [red] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]